# java/android - long is set to -1 for no apparent reason

Tags: java, android, constructor, field, long-integer

I'm calling a constructor with a long. The long field, however, gets set to -1:

LogCat: "set the pack's id to -29270339915449391104. getID() now returns -1"

I have no idea why. If you put in a long then there shouldn't be any conversion issues? What am I missing?

```
private long ID;

public AFileOrPackView(Context context, long ID) {
    super(context);

    this.ID = ID;
    Log.d("asd", "set the pack's id to " + ID + ". getID() now returns " + this.getId());
}

public Long getID() {
    return this.ID;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a typo in your code.

`this.getId()`

should be

```
this.getID()
```

Also, if you do not need, instead or returning a `Long` object you should return the `long` primitive type.
Change :

```
public Long getID() {
    return this.ID;
}
```

in

```
public long getID() {
    return this.ID;
}
```

Comment: That second `)` is closing the `Log's` `d` method. Not a typo.

Comment: @RobAveryIV what are you talking about?

Comment: @blackbelt my bad, at first you had two `)`. Thought that was the "typo" you were talking about.

Comment: @blackbelt, Like the OP says, "... -1 for no apparent reason" ;)

Comment: Wow, u guys r really fast.
Thanks for the help!
I was indeed calling the getId() with a lowercase d - which comes from Android.View.

Answer (score 1):

Are you extending an existing Android View type? If you attempt to return a View's id that is not part of a layout file with an id, or explicitly given an id, the inherited id value will be -1 to denote NO_ID.

Just a thought, hard to tell whether this is the case with the limited information in the question.

Comment: that's absolutely the case, you are right.
Thanks for the help!